# Realm with Gson Child Update Error

Tags: java, android, realm

i have a user Json with the following structure, i'm using Gson and Realm to save it.

```
{
    "id": 2204,// this id is unique
    "name": "Test Name",
    "session_token": "someexmapletoken",
    "account_id": 1,
    "account_name": "S",
    "permissions": {
        "permision_one": true,
        "permision_two": true,
        "permision_tree": false

    }
}
```

my User object is:

```
public class User extends RealmObject {

 @SerializedName("id")
 @Expose
 @PrimaryKey
 private Integer id;
 @SerializedName("name")
 @Expose
 private String name;
 @SerializedName("session_token")
 @Expose
 private String sessionToken;
 @SerializedName("account_id")
 @Expose
 private Integer accountId;
 @SerializedName("account_name")
 @Expose
 private String accountName;
 @SerializedName("permissions")
 @Expose
 private Permissions permissions;
 //omitted getters and setters
}

public class Permissions extends RealmObject{

 @SerializedName("permision_one")
 @Expose
 private Boolean permisionOne;
 @SerializedName("permision_two")
 @Expose
 private Boolean permisionTwo;
 @SerializedName("permision_tree")
 @Expose
 private Boolean permisionTree;
 //omitted getters and setters
}
```

Each time some permission changes, i make a new request of the user json, so i'm calling this code:

```
Gson gson = new Gson();
User user = gson.fromJson(json, User.class);
  realm = Realm.getDefaultInstance();

  realm.executeTransaction(new Realm.Transaction() {
    @Override
    public void execute(Realm realm) {
      realm.insertOrUpdate(User);
    }
  });
```

if the user id remains the same, the same realm User is updated, but each time i call this code a new Permission object is created. there's a way to also update the Permission child object using Gson?

Comment: For that, both `User` and `Permissions` classes need a `@PrimaryKey` annotated field

Comment: in the case of my example json in the permission i cant create a primary key from the json, there is a way to do this, without any json modifications?

Comment: `user.getPermissions().setId(user.getId())`

Comment: this works fine but, User user = gson.fromJson(json, User.class); is no longer valid, but i'll do this approach, thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Realm Just Checks the PrimaryKey to see if the object exist,
before you insert your object 
first set PrimaryKey for your object

```
Permissions item = realm.where(Permissions.class).equalTo("permisionOne", permisionOne).equalTo("permisionTwo", permisionTwo).equalTo("permisionThree", permisionThree).findFirst();
if(item != null)
user.getPermissions().setId(item.id)
```

and after that try your code. by this if the id exist, Realm tries to update it

Answer (score 0):

If you are sure that each `Permissions` belongs to single `User`, you can delete it before updating a `User`.

```
Gson gson = new Gson();
User user = gson.fromJson(json, User.class);
  realm = Realm.getDefaultInstance();

  realm.executeTransaction(new Realm.Transaction() {
    @Override
    public void execute(Realm realm) {
      User existingUser = realm.where(User.class).equalTo("id", user.gtId()).findFirst();
      if (existingUser != null) {
          existingUser.getPermisions().deleteFromRealm();
      }

      realm.insertOrUpdate(user);
    }
  });
```